# I cannot set up my debugger correctly with Qt Creator 3.3.0 Based on Qt 5.4.0 (Clang 6.0 (Apple), 64 bit)

Tags: c++, qt

It used to function normally and then the console opened up. Now when I try to debug it, it says this:

12:53:50: Führe Schritte für Projekt travelcost aus...
12:53:50: Unveränderte Konfiguration, qmake-Schritt wird übersprungen.
12:53:50: Starte "/usr/bin/make" 
make: Nothing to be done for `first'.
12:53:50: Der Prozess "/usr/bin/make" wurde normal beendet.
12:53:50: Verstrichene Zeit: 00:00.

Comment: Can you translate the output in english please?

Comment: Qt Creator 3.6.1 exists, you could try to update and see if that fixes it.

Comment: 12:53:50: Make steps for project cost travel from ...
12:53:50: Unchanged configuration , qmake step is skipped .
12:53:50: Start "/usr/bin/make" make: Nothing to be done for `first'.
12:53:50: The process " / usr / bin / make " ended normally.
12:53:50: Elapsed time : 00:00 .

Comment: Updating helped, thanks!